# Sort 2d dict by the values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a 2d dict like this:
 
`{'John' : {'a' : 9, 'b' : 2, 'c': 5}, 'Smith' : {'d' : 1, 'r' : 3, 'f': 4}}`

And I want to print/save them, sorted, like this:
John a 9
John c 5
Smith f 4
Smith r 3
John b 2
Smith d 1

Such that they are sorted by their inner value. both keys are not known beforehand.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start by making a list of three dimension tuple as follows, where the first element is the key of the outer dictionary, and the second and third element is the key and value of inner dictionary

```
dict = {'John' : {'a' : 9, 'b' : 2, 'c': 5}, 'Smith' : {'d' : 1, 'r' : 3, 'f': 4}}

tuples = []
for key, value in dict.items():
    for k, v in value.items():
        tuples.append((key, k, v))
#[('John', 'a', 9), ('John', 'b', 2), ('John', 'c', 5), 
#('Smith', 'd', 1), ('Smith', 'r', 3), ('Smith', 'f', 4)]
```

We then sort this list on the last element in reverse, and print out the result as follows.

```
sorted_tuples = sorted(tuples, key=lambda x:x[-1], reverse=True)
for a,b,c in sorted_tuples:
    print(a, b, c)
#John a 9
#John c 5
#Smith f 4
#Smith r 3
#John b 2
#Smith d 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to expand the dictionary and afterwards perform sorting:

```
two_dimensional_dictionary = {'John' : {'a' : 9, 'b' : 2, 'c': 5}, 'Smith' : {'d' : 1, 'r' : 3, 'f': 4}}

values = [(first_key, second_key, value) 
          for first_key, values in two_dimensional_dictionary.items() 
          for second_key, value in values.items()]
print(list(sorted(values, key=lambda x:x[-1], reverse=True)))
```

Output:

```
[('John', 'a', 9), ('John', 'c', 5), ('Smith', 'f', 4), ('Smith', 'r', 3), ('John', 'b', 2), ('Smith', 'd', 1)]
``
```